After updating to Xubuntu 24.10, WebGL no longer works on Firefox (v. 131.03.03) due to nvidia-driver-560
After updating to Xubuntu 24.10 from 24.04, WebGL no longer works on Firefox (v. 131.03.03), while it works fine in Chrome.
In about:support I see:
Driver Informations WSI WebGL 1 -
Renderer driver WebGL 1 WebGL creation failed:

WebglAllowWindowsNativeGl:false restricts context creation on this system. ()
Exhausted GL driver options. (FEATURE_FAILURE_WEBGL_EXHAUSTED_DRIVERS)

Renderer driver WebGL 2 WebGL creation failed:

AllowWebgl2:false restricts context creation on this system. ()

webgl.enable-prototype-webgl2 is set to true
webgl.force is set to   true
webgl.osmesalib is set to   true
Wayland has not yet been implemented on Xubuntu, so I am still using X11.
I have the same issue even when running Firefox in safe mode.
After a few attempts, it seems the issue is related to the Nvidia drivers.
I uninstalled the drivers using the command:
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver
rebooted the system (now running with the Nouveau drivers), and the sites with WebGL worked.
Then I rebooted into maintenance mode and tried to install the previous drivers, nvidia-driver-535, but it seems they are no longer available in Xubuntu 24.10. In fact, nvidia-driver-560 is installed along with some files from nvidia-driver-535, so the problem reappeared.
I have an Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 Super.
Any suggestions?

Does it help when you switch from snap to apt version of firefox? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

It seems the issue is related to the Nvidia drivers.I uninstalled the drivers using the command sudo apt purge nvidia-driver*, rebooted the system (now running with the Nouveau drivers), and the sites with WebGL worked. Then I rebooted into maintenance mode and tried to install the previous drivers, nvidia-driver-535, but it seems they are no longer available in Xubuntu 24.10. In fact, nvidia-driver-560 is installed along with some files from nvidia-driver-535, so the problem reappeared. I have an Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 Super.

Firefox 133 : first time I discovered webgl is not working anymore in XOrg session. It is working in Wayland session.
On original Ubuntu 24.10 install, webgl was working on XOrg too.
With XOrg, webgl is working in Chromium.
this is a firefox issue. But Firefox upstream or Ubuntu snap ?

I had the same problem after upgrading to 24.10 : WebGL was not working on Firefox, and impossible to launch the snapstore because of WebGl unavailable.
I used Synaptics to remove the nvidia drivers, and now everything works just fine.

I had already tried uninstalling the Nvidia drivers and switching to Nouveau drivers, and it worked even if the graphics acceleration wasn't optimal.
I also tried reinstalling Xubuntu 24.10 from scratch, but the problem persists. Maybe there is a compatibility issue between the nvidia-drivers-560 and my graphics card, a GeForce RTX 2070 Super.

Adding to confirm I have a 1660 Super and I am in the same situation
